# How to format the date using NSDateFormatter in Swift for iOS?

Tags: ios, regex, swift, date, nsdateformatter

I am trying to parse this date  "18th of June 2016. Saturday" to "18/06/2016" 
I'm aware this can be done using the regex method but I'm not sure how you'd get an output using that.

A method using NSDateFormatter in swift would be preferred

Comment: Using `NSDateFormatter` is the proper solution. Using a regex is not at all how you should do this. Update your question with what you have tried so far.

Comment: Perhaps read the documentation.

Comment: Apple documentation for `NSDateFormatter`: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/ . If you are having a specific problem with `NSDateFormatter` then edit your question to include the code and the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

`NSDateFormatter` does not support days with ordinal indicators, so you have to get rid of them. You can use regex:

```
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[st|nd|rd|th]", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions())
    regex.replaceMatchesInString(dateString, options: NSMatchingOptions(), range: NSMakeRange(0, 4), withTemplate: "")
```

then you simply format the date. 

Complete code:

```
    let dateString = NSMutableString(string: "18th of June 2016. Saturday")

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[st|nd|rd|th]", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions())
        regex.replaceMatchesInString(dateString, options: NSMatchingOptions(), range: NSMakeRange(0, 4), withTemplate: "")

        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
        formatter.dateFormat = "d' of 'MMMM y'.' EEEE"
        let date = formatter.dateFromString(dateString as String)
        formatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
        formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
        let output = formatter.stringFromDate(date!)
        print(output)

    } catch let error as NSError { print(error) }
```

Keep in mind that `NSNumberFormatter` will format according to the current locale settings.

Comment: Since the original date string is in a specific language (English), you are going to need to set the date formatter's locale to an English locale.

Comment: @rmaddy you're absolutely right. I've updated my answer