# Change the NSDate formatter to convert string to desired style

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How to change the date formatter of `1st Dec 1984` String value to 2022-12-01

What will be the required Date formatter style?

Comment: `NSDateFormatter` does not support ordinal numbers like 1st.

Comment: How to resolve this then? @vadian

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733659/how-to-format-the-date-using-nsdateformatter-in-swift-for-ios/37737070#37737070

Comment: Great help (as always) @vadian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer isn't pretty by any means. But it will get the job done. What's difficult is the 'st' in 1st. As far as I know there isn't a date format for that.

```
let dateString = "1st Dec 1984".replacingOccurrences(of: "[st|nd|th|rd]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
let formatter = DateFormatter()

formatter.dateFormat = "d MM yyyy"

let date = formatter.date(from: dateString)

formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let newString = formatter.string(from: date!)
```

This will give you your desired results. Except I'm not sure how you get the 2022 in your result since that can never be produced from your given date.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Can you improve your answer by using `regular expression` rather than replacingOccurrences.

Comment: You can also combine `replacingOccurrences` with regular expression, this is still easier: `let newString = dateString.replacingOccurrences(of: "[st|nd|th|rd]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)`